# Flask, SQLAlchemy error (invalid transaction)

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a flask website. Sometimes on some requests it returns this error:

> Exception message: Can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled
>   back (original cause: InvalidRequestError: Can't reconnect until
>   invalid transaction is rolled back) u'SELECT a_auth2_user.id AS
>   a_auth2_user_id, a_auth2_user.username AS a_auth2_user_username,
>   a_auth2_user.fullname AS a_auth2_user_fullname, a_auth2_user.email AS
>   a_auth2_user_email, a_auth2_user.password AS a_auth2_user_password,
>   a_auth2_user.plain_password AS a_auth2_user_plain_password,
>   a_auth2_user.legacy_password AS a_auth2_user_legacy_password,
>   a_auth2_user.active AS a_auth2_user_active, a_auth2_user.is_admin AS
>   a_auth2_user_is_admin, a_auth2_user.phone AS a_auth2_user_phone,
>   a_auth2_user.last_activity AS a_auth2_user_last_activity \nFROM
>   a_auth2_user \nWHERE a_auth2_user.id = %s \n LIMIT %s'
>   [immutabledict({})]

The weird thing is that it returns this error "sometimes"! and sometimes it works fine. 
Is it something like memory issue?! How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Because your previous commit may be got some exception you should roolbak the session if there is any invalid transaction.

```
try:
    transaction.commit()
except Exception, e:
    session.rollback()
```